# django-bootstrap3 python package installation: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'bootstrap3'

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, ubuntu-14.04

I installed the `django-bootstrap3` python package using pip3 in my Linux Mint 17.3 system. Here's the output:

```
Downloading/unpacking django-bootstrap3
   Downloading django-bootstrap3-7.0.1.tar.gz
   Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/django-bootstrap3/setup.py) egg_info for package django-bootstrap3

      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*js' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*jpg' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*jpeg' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*svg' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*js' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*jpg' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*jpeg' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*svg' under directory 'demo'
Installing collected packages: django-bootstrap3
   Running setup.py install for django-bootstrap3

      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*js' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*jpg' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*jpeg' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*svg' under directory 'bootstrap3'
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*.gif' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*js' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*jpg' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*jpeg' under directory 'demo'
      warning: no files found matching '*svg' under directory 'demo'
Successfully installed django-bootstrap3
Cleaning up...
```

Seems like something related to `bootstrap 3` is missing from my system. What is it? What else should I have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the developer of `django-bootstrap3` it's safe to ignore these warnings: [Link to related issue in github.](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3/issues/268#issuecomment-130244713)

---

Issue #268: *install warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'bootstrap3'*:

> **renpj:**
>
> I got these warning during the installation:
>
> ```
> warning: no files found matching '.png' under directory 'bootstrap3'
> warning: no files found matching '.gif' under directory 'bootstrap3'
>
> [...]
> ```
>
> I'm using Django 1.8.2, python 2.7.6
>
> **dyve (owner):**
>
> You can safely ignore these. If anyone knows how to improve the sep
>   process so these warning do not appear, I'd like to know.